# How to save an email with no attachment using Python?

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

I need to save emails and attachments from Outlook to a folder on my desktop. The logic I need is - if the email has an attachment, save the attachment. If the email doesn't have an attachment, save the email.

I made the below sample script to run through an inbox that currently has two emails - one with an attachment and one without. It correctly saves the PDF attachment, but isn't saving the email without an attachment. I used a print to check that the == 0 condition was satisfied and it correctly printed the body of the email but no file is being saved for this email.

I tried changing the filepath to .html.

```
import os
import datetime
import win32com.client #pip install win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants


#output folder
path = r'C:\Users\SJF2\Desktop\Bank'

filename = r'\testfile.msg'

fullpath = path + filename

print(fullpath)

#create output folder
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

#connect to outlook 
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

#Get inboox
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

#Get specific folder contents
email_folder = inbox.Folders['Test']

#Get items from folder
emails = email_folder.Items

for email in emails:

    subject = email.Subject
    attachments = email.Attachments
    body = email.Body

    if email.Attachments.Count == 0: # check if the email has attachments
        email.SaveAs(fullpath)
        
    else:

        for attachment in attachments:
            fullpath = path + "\\" + str(attachment)
            attachment.SaveAsFile(fullpath)
            #print(attachment)
            print(fullpath)
```

Comment: What is the value of `fullpath` just before you call `SaveAs()`? If the first email in the loop has Attachments then `fullpath` will have been changed. So you might not be saving the file to where you think ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are passing a badly-composed file path. After the first iteration the `fullpath` is changed to the file path of the attached file and doesn't contain initial value any longer. Try to use the following code where separate strings are used:

```
import os
import datetime
import win32com.client #pip install win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants


#output folder
path = r'C:\Users\SJF2\Desktop\Bank'

filename = r'\testfile.msg'

fullpathEmail = path + filename

print(fullpathEmail)

#create output folder
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

#connect to outlook 
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

#Get inboox
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

#Get specific folder contents
email_folder = inbox.Folders['Test']

#Get items from folder
emails = email_folder.Items

for email in emails:

    subject = email.Subject
    attachments = email.Attachments
    body = email.Body

    if email.Attachments.Count == 0: # check if the email has attachments
        email.SaveAs(fullpathEmail)
        
    else:

        for attachment in attachments:
            fullpathAttachment = path + "\\" + str(attachment)
            attachment.SaveAsFile(fullpathAttachment)
            #print(attachment)
            print(fullpathAttachment)
```

Be aware, the [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method accepts two parameters, so I'd suggest specifying the the file type to save too.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the paths and added the file type parameters and everything is working as it should.